# Clickable Polygon map in MAUI

Tags: maui

I'm using MAUI and want to generate a map filled with clickable hexagon like this
[image: clickable hexagon map]

How can I implement this?

I looked at the doc and was thinking that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/shapes/polygon might be a solution.

But in order to do this I need to calculate all the points to trace the polygon and I don't know how to make them clickable...

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: How are you generating the map? Have you tried attaching a TapGestureRecognizer to each hexagon?

Comment: Right now I haven't decided on any implementation for the map generation, any idea?

Comment: No, that's your task. This is not a programming service. I'm happy to help with specific problems.

Comment: lol, I'm not asking you to code, I just don't know enough about MAUI ecosystem so I don't know what my options are. Here I'm just asking what are the possible technologies I can use. I will then look at it and implement myself

Comment: You can use Shapes, as you already noted yourself, you can also use SkiaSharp or GraphicsView, as Poulpynator wrote. I don't know anything about your other requirements, but you'll need some kind of logic to instantiate the different polygons and implement some form of hit-detection, e.g. using a TapGestureRecognizer and then figuring out whether the tap was inside or outside of the polygon.

Comment: I would definitely use SkiaSharp for this. I wouldn't attempt to make individual polygons clickable; I'd calculate the position myself. I've done this before in XForms. I'll see what I can dig up and post on GItHub.

Comment: Yes, I would also prefer SkiaSharp for this as it would make hit detection and generation of the polygon much easier than the other approaches. However, it's a matter of choice *(and opinion)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle clicks (and more) on any element in maui with a [GestureRecognizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap). It's seems that on a polygon it also trigger then you click inside the rectangle of the shape but not inside the polygon, althought then there is several of them it doesn't seem to be an issue.

Just so you know Shapes (which Polygon is a part of) follow the same logic as [svg path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) so you can get an already made polygon (or other svg icons for example). Also the points position is relative to the size of the shape not of the window so once you define one polygon you got them all.

Last you can set the position of the shapes in a AbsoluteLayout, here is an example :

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Polygon
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,0,0"
        Points="0 1, 0 3, 2 4, 4 3, 4 1, 2 0"
        Fill="AliceBlue"
        Stroke="Green"
        Aspect="Fill"
        StrokeThickness="5"
        HeightRequest="100"
        WidthRequest="100">
        <Polygon.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
        </Polygon.GestureRecognizers>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="50,75,0,0"
        Points="0 1, 0 3, 2 4, 4 3, 4 1, 2 0"
        Fill="AliceBlue"
        Stroke="Green"
        Aspect="Fill"
        StrokeThickness="5"
        HeightRequest="100"
        WidthRequest="100">
        <Polygon.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
        </Polygon.GestureRecognizers>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="100,0,0,0"
        Points="0 1, 0 3, 2 4, 4 3, 4 1, 2 0"
        Fill="AliceBlue"
        Stroke="Green"
        Aspect="Fill"
        StrokeThickness="5"
        HeightRequest="100"
        WidthRequest="100">
        <Polygon.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
        </Polygon.GestureRecognizers>
    </Polygon>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

And the event :

```cs
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    var polygon = (Polygon)sender;
    polygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

If you want to draw more advanced things in the future you may want to use something like [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.views.maui.controls.skcanvasview?view=skiasharp-views-maui-2.88) (it's a 2d graphic engine) that will give you more control on drawing things and handling events on shapes.

Just so you know there is a [GraphicsView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/graphicsview) element in maui that let you draw on a canvas but it doesn't handle clicks events, you could try to handle the position of the click yourself though.

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer and the other options you also linked.